# unable to toggle breakpoint eclipse marker id not found

Tags: eclipse, debugging

When I hit the code to create a break point. I am getting error saying that **unable to toggle breakpoint eclipse marker id not found**.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse helped me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528321) at bugs.eclipse.org.

The report says the affected version is 4.7.1a. The status of the bug is RESOLVED FIXED in v4.8, so we still encounter this issue with the version 4.7.3a (which is the current while writing).

As a workaround, you can close and reopen the GUI, this makes things normal again.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, just close the specific java file in Eclipse editor and open it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I had to restart the whole Eclipse.